# SQL запрос через UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно вывести запрос следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, если есть товар в резерве, нужно выводить номер документа по нему.

Текст запроса для вывода поддонов:

```
SELECT pal_num,
    pal_prod,
    prd_desc,
    (CASE loc_blocked WHEN 0 THEN pal_loc ELSE pal_loc ||' блок' END) pal_loc,
    rst_desc,
    pal_batch,
    pal_vin,
    pal_cert,
    awacs_core.to_oradate(pal_bbdate),
    loc_name, 
    loc_zone, 
    pal_owner,
    pal_qty cases,
    pal_sqty singles,
    decode(pal_alloc, 1, pal_qty, pal_pickqty) pcases,
    decode(pal_alloc, 1, pal_sqty, pal_saqty) psingles
FROM AWACS_PALVIEW, AWACS_PRD, awacs_loc, awacs_rst
WHERE PAL_CUST = 'DIAGEO' 
    AND PRD_PROD = PAL_PROD 
    AND loc_name = pal_loc 
    AND RST_CODE = PAL_RSTCODE 
    AND PAL_CUST = PRD_CUST
ORDER BY pal_num
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при наличии упаковок в резерве не равном нулю, выводилась подстрока с номером документа и количеством?

Запрос для нижней строки:

```
SELECT wrk_docref, 
    wrk_qty, 
    wrk_sqty
FROM AWACS_WRK
```

Вот примерные таблицы для запроса

```
    create table AWACS_PALVIEW (pal_num INTEGER,pal_prod INTEGER,pal_qty INTEGER, PAL_SQTY INTEGER);
    INSERT INTO AWACS_PALVIEW (pal_num,pal_prod,pal_qty,pal_sqty) VALUES (712005,124353,0,0);
    INSERT INTO AWACS_PALVIEW (pal_num,pal_prod,pal_qty,pal_sqty) VALUES (712015,1242343,1,0);
    INSERT INTO AWACS_PALVIEW (pal_num,pal_prod,pal_qty,pal_sqty) VALUES (789445,104399,0,0);
    create table AWACS_WRK (wrk_docref INTEGER, WRK_PALNUM INTEGER,WRK_QTY INTEGER, WRK_SQTY INTEGER);
    INSERT INTO AWACS_WRK (WRK_DOCREF,WRK_PALNUM,WRK_QTY,WRK_SQTY) VALUES (99999,712015,1,0);

---

**Query #1**

    SELECT PAL_NUM,PAL_PROD,PAL_QTY,PAL_SQTY FROM AWACS_PALVIEW;

| PAL_NUM | PAL_PROD | PAL_QTY | PAL_SQTY |
| ------- | -------- | ------- | -------- |
| 712005  | 124353   | 0       | 0        |
| 712015  | 1242343  | 1       | 0        |
| 789445  | 104399   | 0       | 0        |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Нужно между второй и третьей строкой вывести : Из них по накладной, WRK_DOCREF,WRK_QTY,WRK_SQTY

А у меня получается что в конце выводит юнион

```
SELECT PAL_NUM,PAL_PROD,PAL_QTY,PAL_SQTY FROM AWACS_PALVIEW
UNION
SELECT 'Из них по накладной',WRK_DOCREF,WRK_QTY,WRK_SQTY FROM AWACS_WRK
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам комфортно работать с запросом в практически одну строку? P.S. ваш вопрос вообще непонятен.

Comment: Спасибо, обычно я так и делаю

Comment: Мне надо чтоб Нижняя строка появлялась только тогда когда есть упаковки в резерве. То есть обычно запрос выводит мне поддоны, но когда у поддона есть резерв, должен выводить строкой ниже номер документа и т. Д.

Comment: А с чем собственно проблемы то?

Comment: Не знаю как делать это((думаю что через юнион, а как непонятно

Comment: Сделать что?  Мне не понятно, что именно вам не понятно. Вы написали 2 запроса, вы хотите их объединить через union. А с чем проблема?

Comment: Мне надо чтоб два запроса было в одном. Нижний отрабатывал в случае, если есть резерв. Отработал и дальше пошёл снова первый.

Comment: Вы можете сделать ссылку на sqlfiddle, с минимальными данными для примера и вашим запросом?

Comment: Нет, все что мог я сделал...

Comment: Сложно понять, какая у вас структура таблиц, какие там данные. Мне лениво самому писать скрипты создания и заполнения таблиц. Однако, если вы предоставите скрипты создания и заполнения таблиц, я помогу написать вам ваш запрос

Comment: Я попробую это сделать, подождите немного

Comment: Добавил упрощенную схему в текст вопроса

Comment: Вы проигнорировали просьбу сделать все скрипты, сделав упрощенную структуру. И теперь совершенно не понятно, как понять, что новая строка должна появится между 2 и 3. И добавьте тогда в вопрос, как должен выглядеть ожидаемый результат на этой структуре

Comment: Строка два значит, что этот поддон имеет резерв. Соответственно из таблицы AWACS_WRK нужно следующей строкой указать номер документа, которым она зарезервирована. Остальные строки резерва не имеют, поэтому все идет по порядку

Comment: А если будет 2 позиции, имеющие резерв. Как в такой ситуации понять?

Comment: так как на картинке из MS EXCEL вначале

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84856/discussion-between-viktorov-and-mishustiq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для упрощенного примера:

```
select pal_num, 
       PAL_PROD, 
       PAL_QTY, 
       PAL_SQTY
from (       
  SELECT to_char(PAL_NUM) as pal_num, 
         PAL_PROD, 
         PAL_QTY, 
         PAL_SQTY,
         1 as rn,
         pal_num as pal_num_ordered
  FROM   AWACS_PALVIEW
  union all 
  SELECT 'Из них по накладной',
         wrk_docref, 
         wrk_qty, 
         wrk_sqty,
         2 as rn,
         pal_num as pal_num_ordered
  FROM   AWACS_WRK t1
  inner  join AWACS_PALVIEW t2
  on     t1.wrk_palnum=t2.pal_num
  )
order  by pal_num_ordered, rn;
```